# Clickable elements behind and within a transparent div container

Tags: html, transparent, clickable

Is there a way to make elements behind a transparent div container clickable AND also secure that elements within this transparent div container stay clickable?

Comment: Of course i mean a div with a transparent background!

Answer (score 0):

Use css property pointer-events like so:

```
pointer-events:none;
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aekvk5nb/)

Comment: When i use the property "pointer-events:none;" only elements behind the div are clickable but not elements within the div container.